# Optimize Memory Java String Array

Tags: java, strings, memory-optimization, hash-map

I was trying to solve one programming challenge :

> First input is a list of connections which is made of pair of IPv4
> address.  Each IP has its own state which starts with false, each
> connection also has state which is made up by logical AND of state of
> its IPs
>
> Second input is a toggle IPs list , these toggles the state of IP
> address ( false to true or true to false). For each toggle action ,
> calculate the impact on connections which is defined as how many
> connections state changed due to change in one IP address.

I solved the above challenge by using below Java program, but I'm not sure if there could be any scope of improvement for memory consumption and run time.
Please pardon my programming knowledge, I would appreciate any positive feedback to cover corener cases

```
public class NumberOfDevices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [][]connections ={{"192.167.0.0","192.167.0.1"},{"192.167.0.2","192.167.0.0"},{"192.167.0.0","192.167.0.3"}};
        String []toggleIps= {"192.167.0.1","192.167.0.0","192.167.0.2","192.167.0.0", "0.0.0.0"};
        int[] result = numberOfDevices(connections, toggleIps);
        
        for(int i:result) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] numberOfDevices(String[][] connections, String [] toggleIps) {
        int count =0;
        int [] result = new int[toggleIps.length];
        if(connections.length>0) { // already a given contaraint that the length of toggle IPs is >=1


            Map<String,Ipv4Address> ip = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i=0; i<connections.length; i++) {
                Ipv4Address ip1, ip2;
                
                if(!ip.containsKey(connections[i][0])) {
                    ip.put(connections[i][0], new Ipv4Address(connections[i][0]));                  
                }
                if(!ip.containsKey(connections[i][1])) {
                    ip.put(connections[i][1], new Ipv4Address(connections[i][1]));                  
                }
                
                ip1=ip.get(connections[i][0]);
                ip2=ip.get(connections[i][1]);
                
                ip1.addConnection(ip2);
                ip2.addConnection(ip1);

            }
            
            for(int j=0; j<toggleIps.length; j++) {
                if(!ip.containsKey(toggleIps[j])) {
                    result[j]=0;
                }
                else {
                    Ipv4Address ipv4 = ip.get(toggleIps[j]);
                    ipv4.setState(!(ipv4.getState()));
                    for(Ipv4Address conn:ipv4.getConnections()) {                       
                        if(conn.getState()) {
                            result[j]++;
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        return result; 
    }

}

// class representing the IPv4 address , it has IP address, current state and the connections where its present
class Ipv4Address{
    String ipAddress;
    boolean state;
    List<Ipv4Address> connections;
    

    public Ipv4Address(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.state=false;
        connections= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean getState() {
        return this.state;
    }
    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state=state;
    }

    public void addConnection(Ipv4Address ipaddress) {
        this.connections.add(ipaddress);
    }
    public List<Ipv4Address> getConnections(){
        return this.connections;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked about memory and run-time impact, I'll focus on memory.

### Memory

**IPv4**

You store a IPv4 address as `String`. In Java a `String` can be represented by a `byte` per character, so 192.167.0.1 becomes 11 bytes.  Also a String is internally a reference, which also costs 8 bytes on 64 bit.

`192.167.0.1` will therefore cost at least 11 + 8 = 19 bytes.

A IPv4 addres could be represented as an `int` (32 bit), because a IPv4 address consist of 4 bytes. This saves a lot of room.

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16642424/461499

**List of connections**

If you really want to squeeze, you could not initialize the list of connections (saving an empty `ArrayList` when there are no connections). Just create it on the fly in the setter and make the getter return `Collections.emptyList()` if the internal list is `null`

If the list of connections becomes *really* long, you might consider storing them in an special datastructure, for example as packed integer list.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Review, it seems me there is no much space for improvement, just some little tips:

```
class Ipv4Address {
    String ipAddress;
    boolean state;
    List<Ipv4Address> connections;
   
    //setters and getters
}
```

Probably you included your `Ipv4Address` class inside the `NumberOfDevices` class file but for a cleaner code better create a `Ipv4Address` class file separated. If you have defined setters and getters, you can encapsulate fields into the class using the `private` access modifier like below:

```
public class Ipv4Address {
    private String ipAddress;
    private boolean state;
    private List<Ipv4Address> connections;

    public Ipv4Address(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.state = false;
        this.connections = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

No much to say about `NumberOfDevices`; in its `numberOfDevices` method you have the following code :

```
public static int[] numberOfDevices(String[][] connections, String [] toggleIps) {
    int count =0;
    int [] result = new int[toggleIps.length];
    if(connections.length>0) { // already a given contaraint that the length of toggle IPs is >=1
    
    
       Map<String,Ipv4Address> ip = new HashMap<>();
       for(int i=0; i<connections.length; i++) {
          Ipv4Address ip1, ip2;
                    
          if(!ip.containsKey(connections[i][0])) {
            ip.put(connections[i][0], new Ipv4Address(connections[i][0]));                  
          }
          if(!ip.containsKey(connections[i][1])) {
            ip.put(connections[i][1], new Ipv4Address(connections[i][1]));                  
          }
                    
          ip1=ip.get(connections[i][0]);
          ip2=ip.get(connections[i][1]);
                    
          ip1.addConnection(ip2);
          ip2.addConnection(ip1);
    
     }

      //other lines
}
```

You can rewrite this part of your method using a foreach construct like below:

```
public static int[] numberOfDevices(String[][] connections, String[] toggleIps) {
    int[] result = new int[toggleIps.length];

    if (connections.length == 0) { return result; }

    Map<String, Ipv4Address> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String[] connection : connections) {

        for (String c : connection) {

            if (!map.containsKey(c)) {
                map.put(c, new Ipv4Address(c));
            }
        }

        Ipv4Address ip1 = map.get(connection[0]);
        Ipv4Address ip2 = map.get(connection[1]);
        ip1.addConnection(ip2);
        ip2.addConnection(ip1);
   }

   //other lines
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @dariosicily said, hide the members of the `Ipv4Address` class; since it's a bad habit to expose internal values directly, since you will lose control over your own data when the object is [mutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html). In your `Ipv4Address` class, the list `connections` is mutable, and can be edited from anywhere; even if you create a getter / setter.

When dealing with `mutable` objects, it always a good practice to return a new instance in the getter. Luckily, with the Java collections, you can use the `java.util.Collections#unmodifiableList` to return a list that is not editable.

```java
    public List<Ipv4Address> getConnections() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.connections);
    }
```

Comment: I'm agree with you, your approach avoids misleading scenarios with generic users.